# Can I add local and remote notifications in my iMessage extension?

Tags: ios, imessage, ios-extensions

I'm building a iMessage extension and I want to add notifications. Can I add notifications to it?

Comment: No, you there is no any public API for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notification handling would be done by the host app, not the extension.